# Include IUs via category.xml without categorizing them with Tycho

Tags: eclipse, tycho

Since [Tycho 0.23](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes/0.23) it is possible to include installable units (IUs) into the final p2 repository by declaring them in the `category.xml`

For example, to include a Gson parser that is required by one of my bundles, I can write the following:

```xml
<iu id="com.google.gson">
  <query> 
    <expression type="match">
      id == com.google.gson &amp;&amp; version &gt;= 2.2.0 &amp;&amp; version &lt; 3.0.0
    </expression>
  </query>
</iu>
```

The IUs to be included are only meant to fulfil dependencies of the main features of the repository. They are not meant to be installed on their own.

Previously I was using the [tycho-extras `mirror` goal](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Additional_Tools#mirror_goal) to include additional IUs and though I thought that I could now move the 'include IUs' directives to the `category.xml` which spares me to redundantly maintain repository URLs.

But unfortunately the IUs that are included via the `category.xml` appear under an *Uncategorized* category when the generated repository is shown in the Eclipse *Install Software* dialog.

[Documentation is sparse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/category.xml), thus I'm asking here if there is a way exclude IUs from any category or define a 'hidden' category?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem a way to add IUs to a `category.xml` without having them categorized, i.e. they will always show up in a category.

However, there are two workarounds available:

(1) To include all dependencies (including transitive dependencies) in your final p2 repository set configuration option `includeAllDependencies` to `true` in the `pom.xml` configuration of the `p2-repository-plugin`. The downside is that this will really include everything, i.e. if you are developing an Eclipse plug-in the final repository will include a ton of Eclipse plug-ins such as Eclipse Platform, Equinox, SWT. Not sure this is wanted.

(2) If you don't mind some post processing you can remove the "Uncategorized" category after building the repository. There is a p2.remove.iu Ant task.

```
<p2.remove.iu>
  <repository location="file://${repositoryOnBuildMachine}" />
  <iu query="property[@name='org.eclipse.equinox.p2.name' @value='Uncategorized']" />
</p2.remove.iu>
```

Sources:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/404103
- https://www.eclipse.org/lists/tycho-user/msg03759.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the update site running but not showing any IU/Category, simply remove the `<iu>...</iu>` tags (and the content inside). In other words,  keep your category.xml file empty.

You will see that the generated content.xml file will list all the IUs, but when browsing none will be "installable".

Here (https://github.com/antoine-morvan/p2-repo-example) is a sample project that builds a P2 repo from Maven dependencies using custom category.xml. Only one dependency is included, jgraph:5.13 along with its source, resulting in two bundles. In the provided category.xml, categories are defined, but no feature/iu is.

After you generate the site and browse it with Eclipse, nothing will be shown. However, if you look at the content of content.xml, you will see that the bundles are correctly provided. That means this p2 repository can be used/referenced for missing dependencies, custom installs...

Hope that helps, best regards.

Comment: The linked example isn't using Tycho. Thus, I believe this is either a feature or a bug (works by accident) the org.reficio p2-maven-plugin.

Answer (score -1):

looking at the very sparse documentation (I also agree) I think you can add the category in your  element. Such as this :

```
<iu id="com.google.gson">
   <category name="javax"/> <<<<<<- here 
  <query> 
    <expression type="match">
      id == com.google.gson &amp;&amp; version &gt;= 2.2.0 &amp;&amp; version &lt; 3.0.0
    </expression>
  </query>
</iu>
```

Comment: Please re-read the question. How would that _exclude IUs from any category or define a 'hidden' category_?